# Splitting encrypted container into chunks while keeping it mountable without re-assembly

Tags: backup, 7-zip, cloud-storage, veracrypt

I have a subscription to a 1TB cloud hosting provider, offering the possibility to upload any file of any size, based on OwnCloud. I'm planning to use this provider for long-term storage / backups (mainly personal pictures).

I don't trust the organization fully - well, I do somehow, but since they can access my data & since you never know what will happen in the future, I decided to use Veracrypt to make 100GB containers and put my files inside, after which I'd sync these 10 files to the provider.

The syncing, which can only be performed using their sync client, is rather painful to use and hardly provides visibility of what's going on. To give an idea: it's been reading (the only 100GB file so far) from disk the last hour just to index the file. Then it stopped and showed a weird error message, now it's doing the same stuff (I assume) again.

I would like to split the 100GB files into smaller chunks, of let's say 1GB files, to manage this indexing/uploading better. One solution might be to come up with n=1000 1GB Veracrypt containers, but that's not manageable.

**My question**: is there a solution somehow to split the Veracrypt 100GB file into chunks, while keeping it possible to mount the container on the fly?

I know I could use e.g. 7zip to split a 100GB container (even without compression), but that's painful when making changes since the 100GB file needs to be re-assembled (=copied) and split (=copied) each time, eating disk space and requiring lots of admin time.
In other words: would there be some solution out there that can cope with split files and would present it as a virtual one, without the need to rebuild/copy?

I'm open to any other suggestions as well!

Comment: Sync clients don't actually have any way of seeing _what parts_ of a file had been changed. If they detect a file change (especially one made offline), they have to reindex the whole file, even if they're able to upload it in chunks.

Comment: @grawity: no changes were made during the last day since the volume is not mounted. But indeed, given your remark, all the more reason to use split files (even in smaller chunks than 1GB).